# I am able to save data to Firebase but i can't retrieve it

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a new app in Android studio.I saved my data using setvalue to Firebase Database, there was no issue in it. But, when I am trying to retrieve the data from Firebase attaching addValueEventListener to the root reference as below, even the `OnDataChange()` is not getting called nor `onCancelled()` is getting called.

I would have missed something, any helpful suggestions are appreciated.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue()); }


            @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
      System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());}
      });
```

My doubt is while debugging my program either the control have to go in onDataChange() or onCancelled(). But it isn't going. I am putting a breakpoint at line System.out.println syntax in both onDataChange() and onCancelled() fm's but the control is not stopping there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SOLVED

I tried creating new project and saving and retrieving the data from Firebase database was working without any issues.

Then I figured it out that the project on I am getting issues is the which i imported from the legacy firebase.com console. i deleted the below lines in the app level build gradle which is deprecated as per the new Firebase documentation then it worked well.

```
    packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read docs?

> **Important:** The onDataChange() method is called every time data is
>   changed at the specified database reference, including changes to
>   children. To limit the size of your snapshots, attach only at the
>   highest level needed for watching changes. For example, **attaching a
>   listener to the root of your database is not recommended.**

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data

I think it's cause of issue

Everything else looking fine, except `System.out`, I'm not sure it will work, android has it's own logging tool. Try `Log.e`

Comment: While it is generally not recommended to attach listeners to the root, it will not cause the callback to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mDatabase.child("your table name here").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue()); }


            @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
      System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());}
      });
```

Comment: I have tried attaching addValueEventListener at various child level, but still it's not working.

Comment: My doubt is while debugging my program either the control have to go in onDataChange() or onCancelled(). But it isn't going. I am putting a breakpoint at line System.out.println syntax in both onDataChange() and onCancelled() fm's but the control is not stopping there.

Comment: @RafiMdk Please you have data in Firebase database then. I worked several times and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Let me know if this succes

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getValue().toString()); }


            @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
      System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());}
      });
```